# View a .h class

Tags: c++, oop

I was looking at some code and it had the following line:

```
#include "point.h"  // Added by ClassView
```

I understand that "point.h" is a class with members, functions? If yes, how can I view it?

Comment: point.h is a header file.  There is no guarantee to the contents based on the name.

Comment: You read the `point.h` file....?

Answer (score 4):

point.h is a file, nothing more and nothing less.

To see the contents of the file, simply open the file.

Comment: In several programs, you can simply right click the filename, and select "open"

Comment: In other programs, you can simply left click the file twice with your cursor.